remove app.<application name> dataflow Spring Cloud
Is there a way to remove app. from the application.properties on the dataflow ??
I'm trying to launch a batch on dataflow with some properties.
These properties are loaded from another project so they can't start with app.application-name

Properties named in the launch of a task with app.<task-name>.XXX will end up as properties named XXX to the application.
